# React native app is stuck at splashscreen

Tags: react-native

I have one react native app coded with [Ignite Red Boilerplate](https://github.com/infinitered/ignite) and app sometimes stuck at Launch screen (Splash screen) only. Then I go back to previous commit and start the app again, and it starts working as expected.

To help you to find out the solution:

1. I am using this splash screen module : [React native splash screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen)
2. Ignite red comes with one Login [Saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) and I have added another signup saga, and it was working fine till the time I actual uninstall the app and reinstall it, and then when App get installed, it never pass the splash screen.
3. I am not seeing any log any where, tried to run it in Xcode as well but no debug log, how ever I can see following things in Simulator system log and I am pasting some things here.  Hope some body can help me to decode it.

```html
Feb 16 09:46:11 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: Running application NyteVibe ({
     initialProps =     {
     };
     rootTag = 1;
 })
Feb 16 09:46:11 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: Running application "NyteVibe" with appParams: {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
Feb 16 09:46:12 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'el.props.component')
Feb 16 09:46:12 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'el.props.component')
Feb 16 09:46:12 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: action @ 09:46:12.030 STARTUP
Feb 16 09:46:12 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: '%c prev state', 'color: #9E9E9E; font-weight: bold', { temperature: { temperature: null, fetching: null, error: null, city: null },
   login: { user: null, error: null, fetching: false },

Feb 16 09:46:12 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: —— log end ——
Feb 16 09:46:12 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 7 Connection has no connected handler
Feb 16 09:46:13 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 8 Connection has no connected handler
Feb 16 09:46:14 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 9 Connection has no connected handler
Feb 16 09:46:16 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 10 Connection has no connected handler
Feb 16 09:46:16 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 11 Connection has no connected handler
Feb 16 09:46:18 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 12 Connection has no connected handler
Feb 16 09:46:20 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 13 Connection has no connected handler
Feb 16 09:46:21 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 14 Connection has no connected handler
Feb 16 09:46:22 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 15 Connection has no connected handler
Feb 16 09:46:24 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 16 Connection has no connected handler
Feb 16 09:46:26 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 17 Connection has no connected handler
Feb 16 09:46:26 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 18 Connection has no connected handler
Feb 16 09:46:28 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 19 Connection has no connected handler
Feb 16 09:46:30 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 20 Connection has no connected handler
Feb 16 09:46:31 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 21 Connection has no connected handler
Feb 16 09:46:32 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 22 Connection has no connected handler
Feb 16 09:46:34 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 23 Connection has no connected handler
Feb 16 09:46:36 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 24 Connection has no connected handler
Feb 16 09:46:36 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 25 Connection has no connected handler
Feb 16 09:46:38 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 26 Connection has no connected handler
Feb 16 09:46:40 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 27 Connection has no connected handler
Feb 16 09:46:41 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 28 Connection has no connected handler
Feb 16 09:46:42 MAC009s-Mac-mini NyteVibe[1709]: [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 29 Connection has no connected handler
```

As you can see in system log, First 6 entries are my start up actions that are getting fired perfectly. And then this no connected handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an exception:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'el.props.component')
```

Search your project for `el.props.component` - it's going to be a component which is mounted during start-up more than likely. Either that or you're misusing a 3rd-party component which has that code.

Comment: The issue is I am not able to track that only :(

Comment: It was a problem in NavigationRouter.js file. Thanks mate for pointing a right direction :)